# Change Bootstrap grid to 16,67+66,67+20,67

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am using Bootstrap for having a better mobile design.

I am using this grid model:

`.col-md-2` (navigation bar) .`col-md-8` (content)- `col-md-2` (right column)
with following width sizes:

16.66666667 % + 66.66666667 % + 16.66666667 %

But I would like to change `.col-md-2` into 2 different sizes like
10.66666667 + 22.66666667, so I would have 2 different classes or is it possible to change the first used `.col-md-2` class and then the second one in my later integreted css-file, because this classes are in different css id's.
I tried to create 2 own col-md classes, but this don't worked.

My solution in the second loaded css file (don't worked correct)

```
#menu.col-md-2 {width:22.66666667%;}

#rechts.col-md-2 {width:10.66666667%;}
```

The total witdh would be now to long, but I should be like before, because I add 6% to the first class and subtract 6% to the second class.

I want to change the sizes, The first column is to short for a 10inch tablet.

Comment: Did you made it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to create two different classes and apply them as you want.

E.g :

```
.col-md-2.specialCol1 {
// Special size
}
.col-md-2.specialCol2 {
// Special size 2 
}
```

Do you know what I mean ?

### EDIT

I suggest you to use this order :

```
.col-md-3 (navigation bar) .col-md-7 (content)- col-md-2 (right column)
```

To focus on the content.

Then, use the media queries to adapt, e.g. :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .yourCol {
    // Your size
  }
}
```

The above example will apply under 640px width. Detect what you need and apply changes.

Comment: When I create 2 new classes the first column will become 100% width. I read this is because of the mobile-first strategy of Bootstrap .

Comment: And what about the col-xs-n and col-sm-n to manage what you want in mobile screen situations ?

Comment: It would be an idea with `col-sm-` for tablet, but I didn't found my desired width sizes.

Comment: Is it possible to make a simple JSFiddle of you work ? It could be easier to make things ;) I prepared it for you https://jsfiddle.net/sog1oxuq/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95364/discussion-between-grischa-and-alteyss).

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest to not change the standard Bootstrap class widths. Create your own... By the way, why at all you need something like this? 10.6666 is really near the col-md-1, why don't use it? Pherapse you can obtain a good result without the need to create custom withs classes, but simply working with margins and paddings.

Comment: The first column is to short for a 10inch tablet. I could use col-md-1, if a had a third witdh class with is fitting to 100%.

Comment: You can put different withts applicable to different resolution ( "col-md-2 col-sm-3" for example), but what I always think is that if the situation is going to be too complicated, the approach is not the right one. Pheraps you are forcing to many content on a single row